# Terraform: Azure WVD Scale Down not updating host pool sessions

Tags: terraform, azure-rm, wvd

I am using Terraform to deploy/configure Azure WVD. It create all necessary resources and can scale up (adding more wvd host by incrementing the number) perfectly fine. However, when I am reducing the number of hosts, it deletes all the relevant resources but the one thing that is missing is updating the host pool. It currently leaves the WVD hostpool with a host with status "Unavailable". How do it "Remove" the session that is no longer available?

[image]